# Finding Current Enumeration: For file in files

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

Lets say I have:

```
for file in files
    print(file)
```

But what I want is

```
for file in files
    print(x)
```

where x is the iteration # of the current file as the program loops through all the files.

Comment: Welcome to StackOveflow! check out the `enumerate` builtin.

Comment: `for files in files` that might be a typo, but I think i get the desire or goal here

Answer (score 1):

Use enumerate function

```
for ind, file in enumerate(files)
        print(ind)
```